# Are there different methods to call Java from Oracle Application Express

Tags: java, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Friends,

I'm working on a requirement where I need to call a Java API from Apex.

The solution I put forward was to create a Java class, store it the database and add a PL/SQL wrapper and then use it. Which is pretty much what is described [here](http://kristianjones.blogspot.com/2007/05/call-java-methods-from-apex-for-those.html).

Whilst I am happy with this, I am interested to know if this is the only method? are there other options that I could explore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, APEX doesn't have anything special for calling Java Stored Procedures.
So it's the same thing as calling a Java SP from within PL/SQL.

As can be seen **[here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chseven.htm)** there is no other way of doing it beside the one you use now.
I would just add that what you actually call a wrapper is in fact the way a Java SP is published to the data dictionary(it makes it available to the SQL/PLSQL contexts). In your case you do it by defining a top-level call specification. Alternatively you can publish it by defining either a package or an object type call specification. For more details see [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chsix.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Marius and the useful link on call specs.